# Trying to search different types of definitions api discord py

Tags: python-3.x, api, discord, discord.py

I am having an error thrown at me when I try to search a term using the API, so what I am trying to accomplish is if the term is a noun it would print the definition for the noun portion, if its an verb then it would print the verb section.

```
 @commands.command(
        name="dict",
        description="Allows the user to get a definition from Urban Dictionary",
        aliases=['dictionary']
    )
    async def dict(self, ctx, *, entry):
        url = "https://twinword-word-graph-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/definition/"

        querystring = {"entry": entry}
        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-key': self.bot.quote_api_key,
            'x-rapidapi-host': "twinword-word-graph-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring) as response:
                r = await response.json()
                print(r)
            if r['meaning']['noun'] in entry:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{entry}")
                embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f'{r["meaning"]["noun"]}')

                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            elif r['meaning']['verb'] in entry:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{entry}")
                embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f"{r['meaning']['verb']}")

                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            elif r['meaning']['adverb'] in entry:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{entry}")
                embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f"{r['meaning']['adverb']}")

                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            elif r['meaning']['adjective'] in entry:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{entry}")
                embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f"{r['meaning']['adjective']}")

                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

```
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
```

The error gets when it tries to throw the first embed of ['meaning']['noun'], then it doesn't send any more embeds when that happens. The issue, without doing the if and elif I will only be able to search if its a noun or verb I'm trying to make sure that if the word has is a noun or verb i don't have to make another command for it.

Comment: Please specify the error type, description and where the error gets thrown.

Comment: i have edited the error in the original post, sorry for not providing that information